# ¿Como mostrar una imagen atrás de otra al hacer zoom en JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vb.net

tengo un problema y es que no consigo mostrar una imagen atrás de otra al hacer zoom asi como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al dar clic hay una imagen de tamaño mediano que al pasar hace que se haga zoom sobre ella: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá hay parte de mi código

```
<div style="float: left" class="img-zoom-container">
        <img id="myimage" src='<%=vImagenPortada1 %>' alt='No tiene índice' style='height: 240px; width: 240px; float:left'/>            
            <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result" style="margin:-300px 0 0 30px; position:relative"></div>
    </div>
```

y del css :
    
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

```
    .img-zoom-container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .img-zoom-lens {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;
    }

    .img-zoom-result {
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        width: 950px;
        height: 600px;
    }
```

Pero al hacer eso, la imagen que hace el zoom cubre la otra imagen.